# What am I limerick

Tags: riddle, limerick

This is my first post on here, inspired by other questions, but original.

```
I am a gas that you love
most commonly found up above
I have no hues
and convert into twos
when you trap me and give me a shove
```

What am I?

Edit: Here is another limerick to add some more clues.

```
I can be manufactured if able
but down here I'm rather unstable
in space I am found
not here on the ground
it's not me that you love but my label
```

Comment: Cute! I loved it, even though I wasn't able to get it :)

Comment: This is very nice for a first puzzle, but FYI, the acronym you were referring to must be either regional or very rare (or maybe known only to people who read TMZ/People Magazine/etc.; I'm from the U.S. and didn't know it), which was disappointing when the answer was revealed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Sulfur monoxide

```
I am a gas that you love
```

> Chemical formula SO, also short for Significant Other

```
most commonly found up above
```

> Sulfur monoxide has been detected in space, but is otherwise rarely encountered intact

```
I have no hues
```

> Sulfur monoxide is a colourless gas.

```
and convert into twos
when you trap me and give me a shove
```

> When concentrated or condensed, it converts to S2O2
>
>  Source: [Sulfur monoxide - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_monoxide)

Comment: Well done - you got it :)

Comment: isn't SO for stack overflow? it could be a good one too :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody has guessed this yet.
I think it is:

> Oxygen (O2)

```
I am a gas that you love
```

> Humans need O2 to live and breathe. (It is found in both the air we breathe and the water we drink - both crucial requirements for life.)

```
most commonly found up above
```

> O2 in the Earth's atmosphere.

```
I have no hues
```

> O2 is a colorless, odorless gas.

```
and convert into twos
```

> Our respiratory system transfers O2 to our blood where O2 is broken down (O2 -> O, O - twos.)

```
when you trap me and give me a shove
```

> "Trap me" - breathing in. "Give me a shove" - our heart pumping blood where the O2 was transferred before the process of breaking it down starts.

Comment: Great answer but it's not what I had in mind. You really wouldn't want to breathe the correct answer in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Ozone gas

Because

> We love ozone gas since it protects us, it's usually found high in the atmosphere (ozone layer) and converts into O2

Comment: Nope, I'm not Ozone. You're on the right track (but not spot on) with some clue interpretations, but not right with others.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

> Nitrogen Gas (N₂) / Nitrous Oxide (N₂O)
> Or Helium!!!

We love it...

> Also known as laughing gas (N₂O that is)...
> Helium is so light it floats out of our atmosphere...
> Kids and adults like breathing it or using it in balloons
> Its colourless...
> It splits into two...
> It is found above (70% of the atmosphere)...

Comment: Laughing gas is nitrous oxide. If it were nitrogen, we'd all be very happy all the time.

Comment: Wait its helium isn't it OP???

Comment: Nope. When you figure out the clue in the first line, you'll know you have it, the link is indirect, but not tenuous.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> hydrogen

I am a gas that you love

> Hydrogen powers the sun, without which life on Earth could not exist. Who doesn't love that? It is also useful for many technological applications, for example it can be used to store energy and powers some cars, such as the [Toyota Mirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota_Mirai).

Most commonly found up above

> The sun, which is up above, has lots of it, although it is also quite common on earth (e.g., it is extracted from natural gas and oil). If it escapes into the air, due to its low molecular weight it will rise up to the upper parts of the atmosphere.

I have no hues

> Hydrogen is colorless

and convert into twos
when you trap me and give me a shove

> This refers to nuclear fusion, the reaction that powers the sun: two hydrogen nuclei (aka protons), when trapped in close proximity and given a lot of energy (a "shove"), fuse to form a deuterium atom (and some other things, which then proceed to do more things to complete the fusion reaction cycle, as described for example [here](http://www.nobelprize.org/educational/physics/energy/fusion_2.html)). Deuterium is a hydrogen isotope with two protons in its nucleus, i.e., a "two".

Comment: Good try, but nope. Tenuous (and too literal) interpretation of the first point, nice interpretation on the last point though.

Comment: @jhabbott is it not the right answer, or is it not accepted cause of poor explanation?

Comment: @Alex Not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Clouds

I am a gas that you love

> People love different shapes of clouds and the rain they give.

and convert into twos
when you trap me and give me a shove

> They give us rain by shove. Two parts are rain and the remaining cloud.

Comment: Nope. Go higher.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gunna make a rather, er, crass guess and say it's

> Methane

I am a gas that you love

> Everyone loves their own brand I guess

most commonly found up above

> Methane rises and is one of the big things damaging out ozone layer IIRC

I have no hues

> Methane doesn't have a colour

and convert into twos

> This is where it kindof falls apart, I guess something to do with 'number twos' though Methane doesn't exactly 'convert' into feces

when you trap me and give me a shove

> Erm, should be self explanatory given the above ;)

Comment: No. I've added another limerick to the question with some more clues.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Helium

I am a gas that you love

> Who doesn't love Helium?

most commonly found up above

> Helium rises

I have no hues

> and is colorless

and convert into twos

> 2nd periodic element

when you trap me and give me a shove

> when you put me in a balloon.

Comment: No, this ignores the clues in the second limerick.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> Plasma aka STAR's

I am a gas that you love

> Stars are luminous balls of plasma and who does not love STARS ;-)

most commonly found up above

> Up above the world so high like the rhyme goes.

I have no hues

> Coz they are so far away.. it is tough to guess the correct color of the star.. Always say they are white.

and convert into twos
when you trap me and give me a shove

> Computer simulations suggest in gravity free environment of space, divide to form two copies of original structure.

What am I?

Edit: Here is another limerick to add some more clues.

I can be manufactured if able
but down here I'm rather unstable
in space I am found
not here on the ground
it's not me that you love but my label

> Expensive and unsafe to manufacture plasma..

Comment: No, this doesn't really fit. Stars have plenty of hues, that's how we know their composition. Also, it's not me that you love but my label!

Answer (score 0):

> Oxygen

I am a gas that you love

> Can't live without it

most commonly found up above

> O3 is the most common gas in the ozone

I have no hues

> A colorless gas

and convert into twos
when you trap me and give me a shove

> Oxygen is trapped when we breath it in, and when we shove it in our exhale it is CO2

Comment: No, O2 is found here on Earth and is stable.